# After user has performed an edit - browser back button should take him back to search results not former edit page

Tags: feature-request

Glad to be a member of this fantastic community. I was wondering if you have ever encountered the same problem like me. After performing 2-3 successive edits on a post and clicking 'Save Edits' if you try to return to previous page (search results or whatever) using the browser's back button, you find out that you need to skip your previous edits first until you arrive on the previous page!

I find this kinda of annoying but maybe it is a very small price to pay for such a great website. Anyway if someone can address that it will be hugely appreciated from my side.

Comment: Isn't the edit page the previous page?

Comment: You tamper with the functionality of the back button at your peril.

Answer (score 1):

Since you cannot use the inline edit form, clicking on "Save Edits" takes you to a page that is different from the edit page; for the browser, the previous page is the edit page. It is the expected behaviour.

Once you reach a reputation of 2000 (if I recall correctly), you will be to use the inline edit form, and the "Back" button will not be a problem anymore.